# AndroidManifest icons doesn't seem by Debug

Tags: android, android-studio-3.3

I have been working on the project so far but I got a weird problem.I  ran two days ago my project there is no problem like that but today I got **instant-run/AndroidManifest**.I have checked all file direction of folders no error in the path. All folders are still there. The errors were shown in below **photos**.

debug\AndroidManifest
[image: debug\AndroidManifest]

main\AndroidManifest
[image: main\AndroidManifest]

error:

> resource drawable/logo (aka com.google.fabric:drawable/logo) not found
>   I checked All Folder direction is correct

Comment: I'm sorry, what's the problem exactly?

Comment: Normally my app is working but today I got instant-run error but folder is still there error: resource drawable/logo (aka com.google.fabric:drawable/logo) not found.

Comment: check whether your **@drawable/logo** drawable is present in drawable folder or not !

Comment: drawable folder is still there

Comment: Check ur commits and do back track

Comment: I didn't any processed about drawable folder

Answer (score 0):

I post this here because i am unable to comment but you can try this....

1. Go to Build-> Clean Project ...........may be this will solve your problem.
2. Go to File-> Invalidate Caches and Restart............

may be this will help you. I am not sure about that